# find '*' , '**' and '`' from string and replace with <strong></strong> and <code></cod in javascript, Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

we need to process an "string" and surround all text between '*' and '**' with `<strong></strong>` and similarly the text between backTic with `<code> </code>`. Now I have written the logic, and it works fine as well,  but I am sure, there must be a better way as it is too much code for this simple task of string processing. Following is my code. Appreciate any suggestions.

**input** = `` "*within single star* and **within double start** and this is `backtick string`" ``

**output** = `"<strong>within single star</strong> and <strong>within double start</strong> and this is <code>backtick string</code>"`

```
transform(data: any) {
        if (data) {
            const processDblStar = (input) => {
                const regExforDoubleStar = /(\*\*)+/gi;
                let i = 0;
                const result = input.replace(regExforDoubleStar, (match, matchedStr, offset) => {
                    i++;
                    return i % 2 === 0 ? '</strong>' : '<strong>';
                });
                return result;
            };

            const processSingleStar = (input) => {
                const regExforSingleStar = /(\*)+/gi;
                let i = 0;
                const result = input.replace(regExforSingleStar, (match, matchedStr, offset) => {
                    i++;
                    return i % 2 === 0 ? '</strong>' : '<strong>';
                });
                return result;
            };

            const processBackTick = (input) => {
                const regExforBackTick = /(\`)+/gi;
                let i = 0;
                const result = input.replace(regExforBackTick, (match, matchedStr, offset) => {
                    i++;
                    return i % 2 === 0 ? '</code>' : '<code>';
                });
                return result;
            };

            const processPipeline = (functions) => (inputStr) => functions.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), inputStr);

            const funcArr: Function[] = [];
            if (data.indexOf('`') >= 0) {
                funcArr.push(processBackTick);
            }
            if (data.indexOf('*') >= 0) {
                funcArr.push(processSingleStar);
            }
            if (data.indexOf('**') >= 0) {
                funcArr.push(processDblStar);
            }

            processPipeline(funcArr)(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: dynamic html is a bit tricky, I would look into `render` functions which are part of JS just seems like a more idiomatic way then returning html from a standard function

Comment: Seems you want to implement Markdown syntax. Why not use one of existing Markdown parsers?

Comment: @Amadan I hv not used Markdown parsers but as you hv pointed me so I will look into it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You can use Markdown as suggested by@Amadan, enabling just the subset of features you described: https://github.com/markedjs/marked/pull/660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to group all the text between `**` and `*`. Using this group, you can then use it in your replacing string by referencing it using `$1`. We can also do the same thing with the backticks, however, instead, surround the matched group in `<code></code>` tags.

```js
const str = '*within single star* and **within double start** and this is `backtick string`';

const proccessPipeline = s =>
   s.replace(/\*{1,2}(.*?)\*{1,2}/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')
    .replace(/`(.*?)`/g, '<code>$1</code>');

const res = proccessPipeline(str);
console.log(res);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: This will allow `*mismatched**` asterisks too. You could use a backreference, but I'm not sure how good support is.

Comment: It’s supposed to do two different things based on whether it’s single asterisks or double asterisks.

Comment: @hugo If it's supposed to do two different things, it'd be when you do `*foo*` or `**foo**`. However, I would expect `*foo**` or `**foo*` to either be a syntax error, or to leave the extra asterisk untouched. I would use `/(\*{1,2})(.*?)\1/` instead, like mpen suggests, or break into two different regexps (Backreferences are universally supported in all regexp engines I know of.)

Comment: It was addressed to the author of the answer. Of course what you pointed out is way more concerning and makes the solution non-viable, but your message was not there yet when I commented.

Comment: @Nick Parsons , Thanks.Currently what you have given fulfill my requirement so I am going to accept it as an answer. but curious, is there an way to find out if there is a bad string `*mismatched**` in the input string to be processed in regex??

Comment: @Akash Hi, I believe there is a way to do it such that `*mismatched**` won't be parsed, as suggested by mpen we would use backreferences. However, I'm not a regex expert so I'm not 100% sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

not the best way to do this. but short code.

```js
var converter = new showdown.Converter();
var input = "*within single star* and **within double start** and this is `backtick string`";
var output = converter.makeHtml(input);
output = "\"" + output + "\""
output = output.replace(/<p>/g, "")
output = output.replace(/<\/p>/g, "")
output = output.replace(/<em>/g, "<strong>")
output = output.replace(/<\/em>/g, "</strong>")
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.0/showdown.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are using markdown parser as suggested by @Amadan. Thanks for this solution. I will double check this markdown parsers as I have not used them in the past. +1 for your effort.